What is this einsum operation doing? E = np.einsum('ij,kl->il', A,B)
given
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
B = np.array([[9,10,11],[12,13,14]])

matrix multiplication would be if I did
C = np.einsum('ij,jk->ik', A, B)

but if I don't multiply j in the input instead using k ...
E = np.einsum('ij,kl->il', A, B)

what am I effectively summing across? Is there a way to think about this intuitively? I'm confused because the dimensions end up the same as if it were matrix multiplication.
I've tried playing around with different numbers in the matrices A and B to get a feel for it but I'm wondering if someone can break it down for me so I can understand what is going on in this example.

It’s a sum over every (j,k) combination ([[sum(A[i][j] * B[k][l] for j in range(2) for k in range(2)) for l in range(3)] for i in range(4)]), but I wouldn’t know what related math that represents, if any.

You could think of it as each (n, m) output being the sum of the outer product of the nth row of A and the mth column of B. This is like a matrix multiply, except the matrix multiply uses an inner product rather than an outer product.

This sums A over axis=1, B over axis=0 and computes the outer product:
np.einsum('ij,kl->il', A, B)

np.outer(A.sum(1), B.sum(0))

array([[ 63,  69,  75],
       [147, 161, 175],
       [231, 253, 275],
       [315, 345, 375]])

You could check the individual einsum results:
# sum over 1
np.einsum('ij->i', A)
# array([ 3,  7, 11, 15])

# sum over 0
np.einsum('kl->l', B)
# array([21, 23, 25])

# outer product
np.einsum('i,l->il', A.sum(1), B.sum(0))
# array([[ 63,  69,  75],
#        [147, 161, 175],
#        [231, 253, 275],
#        [315, 345, 375]])


In [211]: A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
     ...: B = np.array([[9,10,11],[12,13,14]])

In [212]: E = np.einsum('ij,kl->il', A, B); E
Out[212]: 
array([[ 63,  69,  75],
       [147, 161, 175],
       [231, 253, 275],
       [315, 345, 375]])

The 'ij', without 'j' on the RHS means sum on 'j':
In [214]: A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[214]: 
array([[ 3],
       [ 7],
       [11],
       [15]])

Do the sum on B as well, and get the same result:
In [215]: A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)*B.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)
Out[215]: 
array([[ 63,  69,  75],
       [147, 161, 175],
       [231, 253, 275],
       [315, 345, 375]])

This is a (4,1) times a (1,3), producing a (4,3) (read up on broadcasting).
Another way is to calculate the 4d product, and sum on two of the axes:
In [216]: np.einsum('ij,kl',A,B).shape
Out[216]: (4, 2, 2, 3)

In [217]: np.einsum('ij,kl',A,B).sum(axis=(1,2))
Out[217]: 
array([[ 63,  69,  75],
       [147, 161, 175],
       [231, 253, 275],
       [315, 345, 375]])


Here is a longer approach:
Note that you have 4 dimensions: i, j, k and l. A has the dimensions i and j respectively meaning k = 1 and l = 1for A. On the other hand, B has got the dimensions j and k thus i = 1 and j = 1.
A1 = A.reshape(*A.shape, 1, 1) #Setting k = 1, l = 1
B1 = B.reshape(1, 1, *B.shape) #Setting i = 1, j = 1

From here, multiply as usual (numpy will do the broadcasting for you)
E1 = A1 * B1

Now notice that in the results you have il meaning you summed over jk ie the 2nd and 3rd axes:
E1.sum((1,2)) # ie i = 0, j = 1, k =2, l = 3. Now select jk to sum over
array([[ 63,  69,  75],
       [147, 161, 175],
       [231, 253, 275],
       [315, 345, 375]])

